# How to add new fields to TreeNode object?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

For example, there are `.Name`, `.Text` fields. What if I need `Type`, `Path` and `Direction` fields, how can I add them to class `TreeNode` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this satisfy what you intended? I've shown these as properties, but omit the {get;set;} and you'll have fields.

```
  class myTreeNode : System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
  {
    public string NodeType { get; set; }
    public string NodePath { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
  }
```

To add myTreeNode instances to a TreeView, you'd do this:

```
myTreeNode node = new myTreeNode();  
treeview1.Nodes.Add(node);
```

If you want to use the Tag property instead of storing these directly in an inherited node, (showing just two properties instead of 3)

```
class NodeTag
{  
  public NodeTag(string path, string direction)
  {
     NodePath = path;
     Direction = direction;
  }
  public string Direction {get;set;}
}
```

Then, in your code that creates the tree, you'll do this:

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
node.Tag = new NodeTag("my path", "South");
treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
```

Comment: What is better, to create class `myTreeNode` like you said, or to store reference to object with all fields that I need in `TreeView.Tag` properties ?

Comment: and do I need constructor to initialisate all fields in this code ?

Comment: If you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag.aspx you'll see that the Tag Property is there to hold additional data for the Node. Yes, you'll want a constructor to initialize them.  You might make them read-only properties and ONLY set them in the constructor.  But there are probably some circumstances in which you'd want to set them as fields on the TreeNode as you initially asked.